# Packing and unpacking *.obb file

Tags: java, android

Good day!

Lets say I have a directory named test. It contains several dirs and files in it.
(dir_1: file_1, file_2 ;  dir_2: file_1, file_2; ... ;dir_5:file_1, file_2;)

I do 
     jobb -d ./test -k key -o data.obb -pn com.example.obbtest -pv 1

And get

```
Slop: 0   Directory Overhead: 0
Slop: 37185   Directory Overhead: 2880
Partial Sector [32] writing to sector: 199
Partial Sector [32] writing to sector: 199
Partial Sector [32] writing to sector: 199
Partial Sector [96] writing to sector: 231
Alignment off writing to sector: 231
Partial Sector [96] writing to sector: 231
Alignment off writing to sector: 231
Partial Sector [96] writing to sector: 199
Partial Sector [96] writing to sector: 235
Alignment off writing to sector: 235
Partial Sector [96] writing to sector: 235
Alignment off writing to sector: 235
Partial Sector [160] writing to sector: 231
Alignment off writing to sector: 231
Partial Sector [307] writing to sector: 8911
Partial Sector [176] writing to sector: 17075
Partial Sector [96] writing to sector: 17079
Alignment off writing to sector: 17079
Partial Sector [320] writing to sector: 235
Alignment off writing to sector: 235
Partial Sector [96] writing to sector: 17079
Alignment off writing to sector: 17079
Partial Sector [224] writing to sector: 231
Alignment off writing to sector: 231
Partial Sector [307] writing to sector: 25755
Partial Sector [191] writing to sector: 33919
Partial Sector [96] writing to sector: 33923
Alignment off writing to sector: 33923
Partial Sector [320] writing to sector: 235
Alignment off writing to sector: 235
Partial Sector [320] writing to sector: 17079
Alignment off writing to sector: 17079
//and so on
```

the file is ready.
Than, as in

```
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html
```

I do

```
jobb -d ./dotest/ -o data.obb -k key -pn com.example.obbtest -pv 1
```

And get:

```
Slop: 0   Directory Overhead: 0
Slop: 0   Directory Overhead: 0
Java.io.IOException: boot sector says there are 0 sectors per FAT
at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.Fat.<init>(Fat.java:112)
at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.Fat.create(Fat.java:96)
at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.SuperFloppyFormatter.format(SuperFloppyFormatter.java:236)
at com.android.jobb.Main.main(Main.java:414)
```

I guess it means I have don packing wrong.
How can I ix that?

UPADATE

I do 
    jobb -d ./test/ -o my-app-assets.obb -pn com.examlpe.obbtest -pv 1 -k 11111111

and that fine

Than
    jobb -dump my-app-assets.obb -d ./undo/ -k 11111111

And I get my files. BUT - they all are less than 1 mb. If I add file bigger than 1 mb I get

```
 Package Name: com.example.obbtest 
Package Version: 1
SALT: -5c0a03daa17137e2

6fbd61c113679c5258231a5439459dd5
LFN = file1 (3rd copy).jpg / SFN = ShortName [?

                                     |/ifl -- 12 3f b 16 18 7c 10 2f 69 66 6c ]
Partial read from sector: 179
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:189)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:859)
at  com.android.jobb.EncryptedBlockFile$    
   EncryptedBlockFileChannel.readDecryptedSector(EncryptedBlockFile.java:292)
at com.android.jobb.EncryptedBlockFile$EncryptedBlockFileChannel. 
   read(EncryptedBlockFile.java:142)
at de.waldheinz.fs.util.FileDisk.read(FileDisk.java:118)
at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.ClusterChain.readData(ClusterChain.java:225)
at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.FatFile.read(FatFile.java:126)
at com.android.jobb.Main.dumpDirectory(Main.java:137)
at com.android.jobb.Main.main(Main.java:315)
```

Comment: Hi, Facing the same problem as you mentioned. Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: I really wish to help you, but I simply dont remember. I managed to make it work by adding simply a lot of files. Try adding some to the package. Sorry - this is not a propper solution, so I didnt post an answer. PS - look here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36981578

Answer (score 1):

I can't say about all of your errors, but know that relative paths lead to `boot sector says there are 0 sectors per FAT` for me. Using `C:\fullpath\dotest\` worked.